# Getting completion suggestions from a database

Tags: android, database, autocomplete

I am trying to retrieve first 5 words from database and set those as text of button for that here is my code

```
String [] deal;
 String text,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
 text=edt.getText().toString();
         deal=db.getAllItemFilter(text);
                 s1=deal[0];
                 s2=deal[0];
                 s3=deal[0];
                 s4=deal[0];
                 s5=deal[0];

                 sug1.setText(s1);
                 sug2.setText(s2);
                 sug3.setText(s3);
                 sug4.setText(s4);
                 sug5.setText(s5);
```

for database query i am using this code but it is not working

```
public String[] getAllItemFilter(String text)
    {
        String [] columns=  new String[]{word};

        Cursor cursor = this.ourdatabase.query(database_table, columns, " word like 'text%' ", null, null, null, null);

        String [] deal = new String[cursor.getCount()];

            int iword = cursor.getColumnIndex(word);
            int i=0;
            for (cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                 deal[i]=cursor.getString(iword);
                 i++;
                 if(i==5)
                     break;
             }

            return deal;

    }
```

can anybody help me to get first 5 suggestions from database .Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the screaming title?

Answer (score 0):

you should first set a "LIMIT=5" at your SQL query end rather than a loop limit, it will save resources. Then you can replace word% by %word% to also match word beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect.  As you have it set up, it is looking for "text*" every time (you forgot to format the query so the variable is used as a variable).

Change your cursor to what I show below if you want words *beginnning with* the supplied text:

```
Cursor cursor = this.ourdatabase.query(database_table, columns, " word like '" + text + "%' ", null, null, null, null);
```

If you just want words *containing* the supplied text, change it to:

```
Cursor cursor = this.ourdatabase.query(database_table, columns, " word like '%" + text + "%' ", null, null, null, null);
```